# EJS File Not Recognizing JavaScript File's Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

I am creating a website, I am using a NodeJS server. In my public folder I have a script named website.js and it has the jQuery code to give a console.log when the h1 is clicked. (Code Below). But when I click on the h1 in the browser it does not work. The file is loaded properly, gives no 404 error and my CSS stylesheet works fine.

Further Testing: I did a simple test to see if it would give back the text when I called the variable (test code below) it responds with: "" (two quotation marks) so it must not be recognizing it.

```js
//Test code
var xyz = $("#testh1").text();
//jQuery Code
$("#testh1").on("click", function(){
     console.log("Clicked");
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/website.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/website.css">
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

 <h1 id="testh1">TEST</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to load jQuery before your script.

   ```
   <script src="https://path-to-jquery"></script>
   <script src="/javascripts/website.js"></script>
   ```
2. You need to wait for the DOM to be ready before accessing any elements in it. You can either do it with the following code:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#testh1").on("click", function(){
            console.log("Clicked");
       });
   });
   ```

or by putting your `<script>`s at the bottom of the `<body>` instead of in the `<head>`.

```
    <script src="https://path-to-jquery"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/website.js"></script>
</body>
```

You're getting an empty string in your test code because your `#testh1` element hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: In which file should I load jQuery? The JavaScript(website.js) or the EJS(website.ejs) file?

Comment: @AnonUser In the EJS/HTML like you already are. You just need to change the order. You can't put a `<script>` tag inside of JS code (well, at least not in that format).

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much!